# vscode PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied:

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

This error seems to be everywhere but I can't find a solution that matches my situation. At one point it could access the folder. Further, I am still getting the error for the folder even when that section of the code was removed. Restarted, ran vs as admin, and confirmed user has full access to the folders. I must have made some changes to the code to break it at some point but everything looks correct. Why is it even calling a folder that's not in the code?! There is no reference in the secrets that I imported either.

error:

```
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: './aws_s3/archive'
```

code:

```
import boto3
import os
import ignore.secrets as secrets
import shutil


# establish a connection
s3 = boto3.client(
    's3', 
    region_name='us-east-1', 
    aws_access_key_id=secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, 
    aws_secret_access_key=secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
)

#Create bucket
bucket_name = 'well-logs'

response = s3.create_bucket(
    Bucket=bucket_name
)

print(response)

# upload files
csv_directory = './aws_s3/'
for filename in os.listdir(csv_directory):
    file_path = os.path.join(csv_directory, filename)
    s3.upload_file(file_path, bucket_name, filename)

# Confirm successful upload
response = s3.list_objects(Bucket=bucket_name)
objects = response.get('Contents', [])
if objects:
    for obj in objects:
        print(obj['Key'])
else:
    print("No objects found in the bucket.")
```

removed section of code (still getting errors without this):

```
# Archive files
home_directory = './aws_s3/'
archive_directory = './aws_s3/archive/'

if not os.path.exists(archive_directory):
    os.makedirs(archive_directory)

for filename in os.listdir(home_directory):
    source_file = os.path.join(home_directory, filename)
    destination_folder = archive_directory
    shutil.move(source_file, destination_folder)
```

The full error even without the archive section in the script:

```
{'ResponseMetadata': {'RequestId': 'KRXB56SRP0ZSNRXY', 'HostId': 'dqLZ6yY8wcwX8zVIIhcemHwnATlu07hxmvs9EyChi/J5airBjle5mlHcD5rBd/VIo/0WqH5+n1Y=', 'HTTPStatusCode': 200, 'HTTPHeaders': {'x-amz-id-2': 'dqLZ6yY8wcwX8zVIIhcemHwnATlu07hxmvs9EyChi/J5airBjle5mlHcD5rBd/VIo/0WqH5+n1Y=', 'x-amz-request-id': 'KRXB56SRP0ZSNRXY', 'date': 'Sun, 04 Jun 2023 21:25:51 GMT', 'location': '/well-logs', 'server': 'AmazonS3', 'content-length': '0'}, 'RetryAttempts': 0}, 'Location': '/well-logs'}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\ds_projects\dcj-manufacturing-oil-rig\upload-aws.py", line 28, in <module>
    s3.upload_file(file_path, bucket_name, filename)
  File "d:\ds_projects\dcj-manufacturing-oil-rig\env\lib\site-packages\boto3\s3\inject.py", line 143, in upload_file
    return transfer.upload_file(
  File "d:\ds_projects\dcj-manufacturing-oil-rig\env\lib\site-packages\boto3\s3\transfer.py", line 292, in upload_file
    future.result()
  File "d:\ds_projects\dcj-manufacturing-oil-rig\env\lib\site-packages\s3transfer\futures.py", line 103, in result
    return self._coordinator.result()
  File "d:\ds_projects\dcj-manufacturing-oil-rig\env\lib\site-packages\s3transfer\futures.py", line 266, in result
    raise self._exception
  File "d:\ds_projects\dcj-manufacturing-oil-rig\env\lib\site-packages\s3transfer\tasks.py", line 139, in __call__
    return self._execute_main(kwargs)
  File "d:\ds_projects\dcj-manufacturing-oil-rig\env\lib\site-packages\s3transfer\tasks.py", line 162, in _execute_main
    return_value = self._main(**kwargs)
  File "d:\ds_projects\dcj-manufacturing-oil-rig\env\lib\site-packages\s3transfer\upload.py", line 758, in _main
    client.put_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=key, Body=body, **extra_args)
  File "d:\ds_projects\dcj-manufacturing-oil-rig\env\lib\site-packages\botocore\client.py", line 530, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File "d:\ds_projects\dcj-manufacturing-oil-rig\env\lib\site-packages\botocore\client.py", line 933, in _make_api_call
    handler, event_response = self.meta.events.emit_until_response(
  File "d:\ds_projects\dcj-manufacturing-oil-rig\env\lib\site-packages\botocore\hooks.py", line 416, in emit_until_response
    return self._emitter.emit_until_response(aliased_event_name, **kwargs)
  File "d:\ds_projects\dcj-manufacturing-oil-rig\env\lib\site-packages\botocore\hooks.py", line 271, in emit_until_response
    responses = self._emit(event_name, kwargs, stop_on_response=True)
  File "d:\ds_projects\dcj-manufacturing-oil-rig\env\lib\site-packages\botocore\hooks.py", line 239, in _emit
    response = handler(**kwargs)
  File "d:\ds_projects\dcj-manufacturing-oil-rig\env\lib\site-packages\botocore\utils.py", line 3088, in conditionally_calculate_md5
    md5_digest = calculate_md5(body, **kwargs)
  File "d:\ds_projects\dcj-manufacturing-oil-rig\env\lib\site-packages\botocore\utils.py", line 3055, in calculate_md5
    binary_md5 = _calculate_md5_from_file(body)
  File "d:\ds_projects\dcj-manufacturing-oil-rig\env\lib\site-packages\botocore\utils.py", line 3067, in _calculate_md5_from_file
    for chunk in iter(lambda: fileobj.read(1024 * 1024), b''):
  File "d:\ds_projects\dcj-manufacturing-oil-rig\env\lib\site-packages\botocore\utils.py", line 3067, in <lambda>
    for chunk in iter(lambda: fileobj.read(1024 * 1024), b''):
  File "d:\ds_projects\dcj-manufacturing-oil-rig\env\lib\site-packages\s3transfer\utils.py", line 511, in read
    data = self._fileobj.read(amount_to_read)
  File "d:\ds_projects\dcj-manufacturing-oil-rig\env\lib\site-packages\s3transfer\upload.py", line 91, in read
    return self._fileobj.read(amount)
  File "d:\ds_projects\dcj-manufacturing-oil-rig\env\lib\site-packages\s3transfer\utils.py", line 370, in read
    self._open_if_needed()
  File "d:\ds_projects\dcj-manufacturing-oil-rig\env\lib\site-packages\s3transfer\utils.py", line 361, in _open_if_needed
    self._fileobj = self._open_function(self._filename, self._mode)
  File "d:\ds_projects\dcj-manufacturing-oil-rig\env\lib\site-packages\s3transfer\utils.py", line 272, in open
    return open(filename, mode)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: './aws_s3/archive'
```

Comment: At a guess, it's because `./aws_s3/archive` is a _directory_, but your code is treating everything it finds in `./aws_s3/` as a _file_.

Comment: If so, how do I make my code read it as a directory?

Comment: That depends.  Do you _want_ to upload files that are in subdirectories?  Or do you want to _only_ upload those files that are directly in the top-level `aws_s3` folder?

Comment: If you do want to upload files in subdirectories, the usual approach is to use `os.walk()`.  I'm sure you can find lots of tutorials on how to use that.

Comment: @JohnGordon you nailed it, I came across os.walk() searching when you mentioned it was looking at it as a file. Was a quick fix from there. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As answered by John Gordon in the comments.

It's because ./aws_s3/archive is a directory, but your code is treating everything it finds in ./aws_s3/ as a file.

Solutions:

1. Remove subdirectories
2. If you do want to upload files in subdirectories, the usual approach is to use os.walk().